# AngularJS / Sqlite / Electron - Unknown provider: $dbServiceProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, electron

I am trying to build electron app which display/retrieve items on the table from SQL database that I created but I get Unknown provider error.

I've tried to follow some solutions on the web but the problem still persist and I don't know where am doing wrong

Here is my angular service which connects to the database (dbService.js)

```
app.factory("dbService", function ($http) {
    var sqlite = require('sqlite-sync');
    var db = sqlite.connect('model/database.db');
    return db;
});
```

Here is my controller (salesController.js)

```
app.controller("salesController", function ($scope, $location, $dbService) {
    $scope.sub = {
        'title': 'Sales Management'
    }

    $scope.listSales = function () {
        dbService.runAsync("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE active = 1", function (data) {
            $scope.sales = data;
        });
    }

});
```

And here is my module (app.js)

```
var app = angular.module('bpApp', ['ui.router', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

Lastly I added this code to display data to my table (sales.html)

```
....
<tbody>
 <tr class="bz-tablecell" dir-paginate="sale in   sales|filter:search|itemsPerPage:8">
     <td id="table-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td style="font-weight: 600">{{sale.name}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.amount}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.quantity}}</td>
                <td><a href="#">{{sale.customer}}</a></td>
                <td>{{sale.date}}</td>
                <td class="export-ignore"><span class="approved" style="border-radius: 0 !important;">{{sale.status}}</span></td>
                <td class="export-ignore"><a href="#">Manage</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
...
```

I've include all the files needed on my index.html which then loads sale.html via ui-view, loads the view okay but data are not retrieved from my database and I keep getting the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $dbServiceProvider <- $dbService <- salesController
```

Please help me to solve it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the declaration of your controller to

```
app.controller("salesController", function ($scope, $location, dbService) {
```

Your dbService factory it's not an AngularJS API's, which has `$`prefix, that's why it can't inject it.

Please, refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#angular_namespace

> $' Prefix Naming Convention
> You can create your own services, and in fact we will do exactly that in step 11. As a naming convention, angular's built-in services, Scope methods and a few other angular APIs have a '$' prefix in front of the name. Don't use a '$' prefix when naming your services and models, in order to avoid any possible naming collisions.
>
> Angular Namespace
> To prevent accidental name collision, Angular prefixes names of objects which could potentially collide with $. Please do not use the $ prefix in your code as it may accidentally collide with Angular code.

Comment: Thank you so much. that solved the error, spend all day trying to figure this out